# Angular2 two routes to one component?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

In Angular 2 I would like to define two routes, which use the same Component, but one route being a special case using a special preset parameter. Now what I want to do is his:

```
@RouteConfig([
  { path: '/',  name: 'Home', component: HomeComponent    },
  { path: '/user/:id', name: 'User', component: UserComponent  },
  { path: '/special-user', name: 'User', component: UserComponent, params:{'userId':'123'}  },
])
```

The thing I need is "params" in the last route-definition to "/special-user". Is this possible at all?

Edit: in the path /user/:id the id is part of the url, but in the special-user-case I would like for the id to be invisible and not to be part of the url

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found the answer in this article:

https://auth0.com/blog/2016/01/25/angular-2-series-part-4-component-router-in-depth/[1](https://auth0.com/blog/2016/01/25/angular-2-series-part-4-component-router-in-depth/)

configure the route

```
@RouteConfig([
  { path: '/myroute', component: MyComponent, name: 'MyRoute', data: { isAdmin: true } }
])
```

inside the component:

```
import {RouteData} from 'angular2/router';

export class MyComponent {
  isAdmin: boolean;

  constructor(data: RouteData) {
    this.isAdmin = data.get('isAdmin');
  }
}
```

Comment: PS:- there is no more `name` while using routing in angular2 RC

Comment: For **Angular2 Release**, instead of `RouteData` you need `ActivatedRoute`. So the constructor would look like: `constructor(data: ActivatedRoute) { this.isAdmin  = !!data.snapshot.data['isAdmin']; }`.
I advise to use the !! as a trick for converting anything (including undefined) to boolean

Answer (score 8):

***Angular 2 Beta.x***

Define route as

```
@RouteConfig([ 
  ...
  { path: '/special-user/:userId', name: 'SpecUser', component: UserComponent}
])
```

Use

inside template

```
[routerLink]="['SpecUser', {userId:123}]"
```

inside component

```
export class SomeComponent  {
  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  someMethod() {
    this.router.navigate(['SpecUser', {userId:123}]);
  }
}
```

***Angular 2 RC***

Define route as

```
@Routes([ 
  ...
  { path: '/special-user/:userId', component: UserComponent}
])
```

Use

inside template

```
[routerLink]="['/special-user', 123]"
```

inside component

```
export class SomeComponent  {
  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  someMethod() {
    this.router.navigate(['/special-user', 123]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Is there a way to have the URL "www.example.com/special-user" use the userID=123 without specifying it in the URL, but rather in the Controller. I want the URL to be pretty without the ID as a get-parameter

Comment: @TobiasGassmann placing `routerLink` in template, generates `<a>` as you know, say you have two user with `id : 1` and `id : 2`, and place two corresponding `<a>` on template without specifying `id`. it's not distinguishable which link should navigate to first user and which to second. There are maybe [techniques to modify URL via Js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page) , but on template, link must contain `id`